# addControl to FormGroup dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

How can I add a FormControl to a FormGroup dynamically in Angular?

For example,
I would like to add a mandatory control which name is "new" and its default value is ''.

Comment: that could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334283/reactive-forms-how-to-add-new-formgroup-or-formarray-into-an-existing-formgroup

Comment: Like Siro answered your question, you can use addControl method to add new inputs to your form group. I have a little project wich studied dynamic forms. I hope which be useful. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eypxbq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 300, accepted):

[`addControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl) is what you need. Please note the second parameters must be a FormControl instance like so:

```js
this.testForm.addControl('new', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
```

You can also add the validators dynamically if you want with the [`setValidators`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalidators) method. Calling this overwrites any existing sync validators.

Comment: Sorry, how do to includo more that one validator, for example 
this.testForm.addControl('new', new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.max(100)]);

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: For me I needed to add formGroup: FormGroup to the type in order for this to work in Angular 14.

Comment: Note that you can add several validators using an array:
`this.testForm.addControl('name', new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.max(5)]))`

Answer (score 69):

If you are using `FormBuilder` for your form, you can also use that for adding a control:

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
    
method() {
  this.testForm.addControl('new', this.fb.control('', Validators.required));
}
```

Comment: how to stop event emit when adding control inside a value change subscription?

Answer (score 10):

simple use:

```
  this.testForm.addControl('new', this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required]
    }));
```

Answer (score 5):

Angular 14 added typings to forms. Here is what the new syntax looks like:

**Form declaration**

```
public form = new FormGroup<{ new?: FormControl<string | null> }>();
```

Note that the `new` control must be declared as optional. You won't be able to use `addControl` if the field isn't declared first.

For a bigger form you can use an interface:

```
interface MyForm {
    field1: FormControl<string | null>;
    field2: FormControl<string | null>;
    new?: FormControl<string | null>;
}

public form = new FormGroup<MyForm>({
    field1: new FormControl<string | null>('', Validators.required),
    field2: new FormControl<string | null>('', Validators.required),
});
```

**Add control to the form**

```
this.form.addControl('new', new FormControl<string | null>('', Validators.required));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-name',
  templateUrl: './component-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-name.component.scss']
})
export class ComponentName implements OnInit {

    formGroup: FormGroup;        
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        lastName:  new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      });    
    }
    
    // Add single or multiple controls here
    addNewControls(): void {
      this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
         ...this.formGroup.controls,
         email: ['', Validators.required],
         phone: ['', Validators.required]
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem in Angular 12. Following code snippets worked perfectly for me.

***Declare the form:***

```
public form: FormGroup;
```

***Create a new control for the form:***

```
this.form.addControl('new', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
```

Comment: This answer worked for me since Angular 14 now made the form groups require types.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new `FormControl` dynamically to only one instance of an existing `FormArray`, use the casting technique.

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    formArrayName: this.fb.array([])
  });
} //

addNewFormArrayInstance(insertIndex: number){
  // insertIndex to insert at a specific position
  const NEWFORMGROUP = new FormGroup({
    'control1': new FormControl(''),
    'control2': new FormControl({value: [], disabled: true}),
    'control3': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    'control4': new FormControl(true)
  });

  // use push(NEWFORMGROUP) if needed
  (<FormArray>this.form.get('formArrayName')).insert(insertIndex, NEWFORMGROUP);
} //

addControlToFormArrayInstance(index: number){
  // index is the FormArray instance's index to which a new control is to be added
  (<FormGroup>
    (<FormArray>this.form.get('formArrayName')).controls[index]
  ).addControls(
    'newControl', new FormControl('new')
  );
} //
```