# Is it possible to add property dynamically to groupform

Tags: angular, forms

Is it possible to add property dynamically to groupform? 
I need a property name to have an index as part of the name

```
createForm() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        this.groupForm = this.fb.group({
            prixName+index: ['', [Validators.maxLength(4)]],
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use addControl function for this

```
this.testForm.addControl('new', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
```

see this answer [addControl to FormGroup dynamically in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573797/dynamically-addcontrol-to-formgroup-angular-5) and this link too https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addcontrol

```
createForm() {
   this.groupForm = this.fb.group({});
   for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
     this.groupForm.addControl(prixName+index, new FormControl(null, Validators.maxLength(4)));

   }
}
```

If you need form control array then use FormArray instead of index or increment counter. This will also helps you in that case
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray