# Angular 2 Reactive Form - Reuse individual form control

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In my Angular app I have a complex entity that can be created in multiple ways: manually, by uploading json files, by importing from another url, etc.

For each case described above, I have build a **separate form**, using [**Reactive Forms**](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), in **separate components**.

All the other form fields are different, except the field for the atrribute called `name`.

The formControl attached to the `name` attribute has the following definition:

```js
name: new FormControl(this.initialValue, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.maxLength(10)
      ])
```

Now, I don't like that I have to repeat the same definition for this form control on every reactive form constructor, which, as I said before, are in **separate components**.

Here are some code snippets:

```js
this.formA = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.initialValue, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.maxLength(10)
      ]),
      fooControl1: new FormControl(''),
      fooControl2: new FormControl('')
    });
```

```js
this.formB = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.initialValue, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.maxLength(10)
      ]),
      barControl: new FormControl('')
    });
```

I have build a simple Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyjnlq.
(for simplification, in the example the forms are in same component)

**Question**:
How can I save this form control and include it in every form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build reusable form, we have to use ControlValueAccessor API.

What is [CVA](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)?

> According to Angular documentation, ControlValueAccessor Defines an interface that acts as a bridge between the Angular forms
>   API and a native element in the DOM.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-nameform",
  templateUrl: "./nameform.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./nameform.component.css"],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: NameformComponent,
      multi: true
    },
     {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: NameformComponent,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class NameformComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  form: FormGroup;
  onTouched: any;
  onChange:any;
  constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.maxLength(10)
      ])
    });
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{
      this.onChange(value);
      this.onTouched();
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
  writeValue(value: any) {
   value && this.form.setValue(value, {emitEvent:false});
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
    get controls() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  validate(control:AbstractControl){
    return this.form.valid;
  }
}
```

> [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dunv1v)

[For Detailed explanationCheck this Blog](https://coryrylan.com/blog/building-reusable-forms-in-angular)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works, except for the initial form validation state. It should be false, since it has required inputs. I've modified the `validate` function, it should not return a boolean; I've modified to `validate(_: FormControl) { return this.form.valid ? null : { valid: false }; }`. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-actcyu

Answer (score 0):

What about storing the Form Definition of the control in a Service which adds the control to the Group with the Form builder like so [dynamically addControl to formgroup Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573797/dynamically-addcontrol-to-formgroup-angular-5)