# Create a generic reactiveForm - dynamic components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a project in Angular and angular material in which I am trying to create generic components to avoid repeating them in all components.

Now I'm creating a component with a form, but I'm having trouble passing fields to it from another component.

I'm following this Angular guide but I don't understand how to adapt it to the component I currently have: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

This is the form component, `form.component.html`, it is the view of the form that will be imported into the rest of the components:

```
<form  [formGroup]="formName">
  <mat-grid-list [cols]="cols" rowHeight="60px" fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let field of fields" [colspan]="field.cols">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [placeholder]="field.name" [formControlName]="field.columnDef">
        <mat-icon matSuffix *ngIf="field.icon">{{ field.icon }}</mat-icon>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</form>
```

This is the `form.component.ts`, currently I get four variables (`formName, cols, fields, buttons`), I'm getting the fields object fine, but **my problem**: I can't build the form from the fields object:

```
export class FormAddComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('formName') public formName: FormGroup;
  @Input('cols') public cols: number;
  @Input('fields') public fields: Fields[];
  @Input('buttons') public button: Buttons[];

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

This is the component from which the form is called, `test.component.html`:

```
<app-form-add [formName]="formClient" [cols]="4" [fields]="fields" [buttons]="buttons"></app-form-add>
```

These are the fields and buttons objects, `test.component.ts`:

export class TestComponent {

```
public formTest: FormGroup;
    
      constructor(
      ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataCars = [
      { id: '01', model: 'BMW' },
      { id: '01', model: 'BMW' },
      { id: '01', model: 'BMW' },
    ];

    this.formTest = this.fb.group({
      name: [],
      lastName: [],
      phone: [],
      email: [],
      car: []
    });
  }

  public fields: Fields[] = [
            { name: "Nombre cliente", columnDef: "name", icon: "person_outline", cols: 1 },
            { name: "Apellidos", columnDef: "lastName", icon: "", cols: 1, valueList: false },
            { name: "Telefono", columnDef: "phone", icon: "", cols: 1, valueList: false },
            { name: "Email", columnDef: "email", icon: "", cols: 1, valueList: false },
            { name: "Car", columnDef: "car", icon: "", cols: 1, valueList: true, nameList: this.dataCars }
          ];
    
   public buttons: Buttons[] = [
        { name: "ADD", icon: "", action: null }
      ];
    
    }
```

UPDATE:
I am trying to add a select field to the form, I have added a boolean to identify if the field is a list and another property indicating the list.

**Problem:**
This causes the following error: Property 'dataCars' is used before its initialization

I am creating the array of objects in the ngOnInit first before using it, I don't know why this happens

Test example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iyhuau?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: this.formName = this.fb.group({}), isn't it empty?

Comment: @Vega Yes, in the formComponent.ts `this.fb.group({})` is empty, that's my problem, I don't know how to pass the values of the fields that I want to show

Comment: Hello, isn't this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573797/addcontrol-to-formgroup-dynamically-in-angular

Comment: @AlainBoudard No, with that I can add controls to the fields, what I want is to add new fields to a group

Comment: Well the method adds field to a group, but if you have nested formGroup, you have to reference them with `formGroupName` like this : https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName ... ok, you do if in the generic component actually.

Comment: @build, as you pass from your TestComponent the formGroup (with the FormControls, name,lastName,phone and email) you **not** use "this.formName = this.fb.group({})". Be carefully, there're severals ways to manage a FormGroup or nested FormGroups. One is create the formGroup in "main component" and pass as Input. Another one is create the formGroup in the "component" and pass the value to the "main component"

Comment: @Eliseo I want to do it all in the main component, FormControl.ts. I just updated the question, I have made some changes: I have added `dataForm: new FormArray([])` to add the fields and two other methods that are responsible for obtaining the properties and generating the fields through the object

Comment: @build try this: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7vqe5c?file=src/app/form/form.component.ts

Comment: @OrShalmayev Thanks, it took me a while to answer, the example works by generating only the form in the component, now I'm trying to add improvements. I have updated the question and the example, I am trying to add a select.

Comment: why use a FormArray???? [relationated SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146224/angular-how-to-create-form-controls-from-an-array-of-objects/73148007#73148007)

Comment: @Eliseo Sorry, I hadn't updated the question, I'm not using the FormArray anymore. Now what I need is to create a dynamic mat-select