# Angular dynamic form group: not binding form inputs to form groups

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular-forms

## Objective

I am trying to create a form in angular that dynamically renders some fields based on an array that is received from the backend.

Let's say that the three possible inputs in the form are `["one", "two", "three", "four"]`.

Then depending on this array, a form should be rendered and the form group should only have inputs mentioned in the received array. In my case let us just say: `["one", "two", "three"]`.

## Problem:

Let's forget the rendering part for now and focus on creating the form group.

As you can see below, the simple code tries to use `addControl` method to dynamically add controls to the form group.

When submitting the code, the fields are present as `{one: null, two: null, three: null}`.

I have subscribed to the `valueChanges` of the form to print out if anything changes.

But when the input of the field `one` is changed, there is no event fired and nothing is printed.

Furthermore, when submitted, the object seems to be `{one: null, two: null, three: null}` as if nothing changed.

My guess is that somehow, the form template is not being *bound* to the code in component.ts , but I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <div>
      <div class="col-5 form-floating">
        <input formControlName="one"/>
        <label>One</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="submit()">SUBMIT</button>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({});
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(): void {
    this.array.forEach((field: string) => {
      this.form.addControl(field, new FormControl(null));
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  }

  submit(): void {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5thwux?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Have you checked this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573797/addcontrol-to-formgroup-dynamically-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot enclosed in a formGroup

```
<!--I use the *ngIf to avoid initial errors-->
<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="col-5 form-floating">
        <input formControlName="one"/>
        <label>One</label>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

BTW, you can iterate over the array

```
<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
      <div *ngFor="let item of array" class="col-5 form-floating">
        <input [formControlName]="item"/>
        <label>One</label>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Even your array can be an array of object in the way `{label:...,field:...}`

NOTE: It's strange you have no errors in console in you didn't enclosed in a formGroup